# Python: Count kmers from fasta files

Tags: python

I want to count the kmers from a fasta file. I have the following script:

```
import operator

seq = open('file', 'r')
kmers = {}
k = 5
for i in range(len(seq) - k + 1):
   kmer = seq[i:i+k]
   if kmer in kmers:
      kmers[kmer] += 1
   else:
      kmers[kmer] = 1

for kmer, count in kmers.items():
   print (kmer + "\t" + str(count))

sortedKmer = sorted(kmers.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
for item in sortedKmer:
   print (item[0] + "\t" + str(item[1]))
```

This works fine for a file with only one sequence, but now I have a fasta file with several contigs. 
My fasta file looks like this:

```
>1
GTCTTCCGGCGAGCGGGCTTTTCACCCGCTTTATCGTTACTTATGTCAGCATTCGCACTT
CTGATACCTCCAGCAACCCTCACAGGCCACCTTCGCAGGCTTACAGAACGCTCCCCTACC
CAACAACGCATAAACGTCGCTGCCGCAGCTTCGGTGCATGGTTTAGCCCCGTTACATCTT
CCGCGCAGGCCGACTCGACCAGTGAGCTATTACGCTTTCTTTAAATGATGGCTGCTTCTA
AGCCAACATCCTGGCTGTCTGG
>2
AAAGAAAGCGTAATAGCTCACTGGTCGAGTCGGCCTGCGCGGAAGATGTAACGGGGCTAA
ACCATGCACCGAAGCTGCGGCAGCGACACTCAGGTGTTGTTGGGTAGGGGAGCGTTCTGT
AAGCCTGTGAAGGTGGCCTGTGAGGGTTGCTGGAGGTATCAGAAGTGCGAATGCTGACAT
AAGTAACGATAAAGCGGGTGAAAAGCCCGCTCGCCGGAAGACCAAGGGTTCCTGTCCAAC
GTTAATCGGGGCAGG
```

How can I change the script that it take first the sequence after ">1", print that output, go to ">2", print that output etc?

Comment: It may exists a library to read fasta file. Google : http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO

Comment: As per the  [FASTA file format](http://bioperl.org/formats/sequence_formats/FASTA_sequence_format)  `The description line after the > is totally free-form`, so difficult to give generic solution. A basic pythonic way is to use regex e.g. re.split('>\d',s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never heard about kmer or fasta, but I think I understand what you are trying to do.

You can try to split on a regex involving '>', but I would recommend processing the file line by line and accumulate kmers before printing them appropriately when reaching the '>1'-lines. See below code with comments

```
import operator

def printSeq(name, seq):
    # Extract your code into a function and print header for current kmer
    print("%s\n################################" %name)
    kmers = {}
    k = 5
    for i in range(len(seq) - k + 1):
       kmer = seq[i:i+k]
       if kmer in kmers:
          kmers[kmer] += 1
       else:
          kmers[kmer] = 1

    for kmer, count in kmers.items():
       print (kmer + "\t" + str(count))

    sortedKmer = sorted(kmers.items(), reverse=True)

    for item in sortedKmer:
       print (item[0] + "\t" + str(item[1]))

with open('file', 'r') as f:
    seq = ""
    key = ""
    for line in f.readlines():
        # Loop over lines in file
        if line.startswith(">"):
            # if we get '>' it is time for a new sequence
            if key and seq:
                # if it wasn't the first we should print it before overwriting the variables
                printSeq(key, seq)
            # store name after '>' and reset sequence
            key = line[1:].strip()
            seq = ""
        else:
            # accumulate kmer until we hit another '>'
           seq += line.strip()
    # when we are done with all the lines, print the last sequence
    printSeq(key, seq)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following with your example FASTA file and it should work:

```
def count_kmers(seq, k, kmers):
    for i in range(len(seq) - k + 1):
        kmr = seq[i:i + k]

        if kmr in kmers:
            kmers[kmr] += 1

        else:
            kmers[kmr] = 1

filename = raw_input('File name/path: ')
k = input('Value for k: ')
kmers = {}

# Put each line of the file into a list (avoid empty lines)
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines() if l.strip() != '']

# Find the line indices where a new sequence starts
idx = [i for (i, l) in enumerate(lines) if l[0] == '>']

idx += [len(lines)]

for i in xrange(len(idx) - 1):
    start = idx[i] + 1
    stop = idx[i + 1]
    sequence = ''.join(lines[start:stop])

    count_kmers(sequence, k, kmers)

print kmers
```

Hope it helps :)